# Find if static file exists before calling in deployment - Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

In production I am able to run:

```
#views.py
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

result = finders.find(f'Images/{var}')
context = {"r", results}

#template.html
{% if r %}
    {% with 'Images/'|add:var as var %}
        <img src="{% static var %}">
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

However, now that my files are being stored in Google's buckets `finders.find(f'Images/{var}')` keeps returning `False` and my images aren't being displayed. I need a way to test if files exists prior to calling them to avoid displaying empty boxes when a variable's image does not exist.

Incase there's a way to search through the remote buckets, here is my settings.py configuration:

```
#settings.py
. . . 
STATIC_URL = http://storage.googleapis.com/env("BUCKET")/static/
STATIC_ROOT = http://storage.googleapis.com/env("BUCKET")/static/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through a bunch of websites (mostly SO,) I found this solution really helpful:

```
{% with 'Images/'|add:var as var %}
   <img src="{% static var %}" class="img" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.style.display='none';src='';this.class='';" />
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use request lib:

```py
import request
r = requests.head(file_url)
if r.status_code == 200:
  do something...
```

but that's gonna cost you a lot (I mean response time, not money)
better solution would be using JS, something like this (this is jquery):

```js
<script> 
$("img").on("error", function () {
  //$(this).attr("src", "broken.gif");  // set default pic
  $(this).hide();  // hide img
});
</script>
```

That way you can hide or change all images in the page, when it doesn't load

Comment: The fact you had my financial interest in mind restores my faith in humanity haha thanks for your help! @MartinBeran

Comment: @Displayname I'd like to say 'you're welcome' but I'm new here and the rules here are pretty strict lol https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/acknowledging-thank-you-comments Now someone's gonna downvote me or something